# How to pass an asterisk(*) to a command inside a Bash script?

Tags: bash, quotes

I have done quite a bit of looking on Google, stackexchange, stackoverflow, etc. So far none of the examples satisfies a quite simple use case for using an asterisk character (not as a wildcard) within a bash script.

The following command examples work exactly as needed in the (interactive) terminal window.  Both commands give the same results.

```
  find  /home/will/ref/  -path "*Java Develop*.pdf"
  #
  target="Java Develop"
  find  /home/will/ref/  -path "*$target*.pdf"
```

The question, and objective, is how to successfully put that command into a script with the `find` target

- "Java Develop"

Passed as an argument?  For a script named, `get-ref` as follows.

```
   get-ref "Java Develop"`
```

None of the following (not the exhaustive) list of attempts:

1. `find  /home/will/ref/  -path \"\*$target\*.pdf\"`
2. `find  /home/will/ref/  -path \"*$target*.pdf\"`
3. `find  /home/will/ref/  -path "*$target*.pdf"`

Plus several variations around those examples including putting the `-path` argument string in a variable -- All so far manage to *split* the target using the space or accept the argument and return nothing.  When used on the command-line, about 3 x files are returned.

To be clear though, I'm not concerned with the space inside `$target` because that side seems to work OK.  Ultimately the `$target` will be a script parameter anyway.

-- ***update*** 2015-12-22 --

It appears that the Bash version is important.  This version is:

```
  $ bash -version
  GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

A friend ran more or less the same options as above and they work.  When I ran his script on my PC, same result, no output.

To answer the questions:

- Everything fails the either by not 'finding' something; or by giving an error about the string "Devel" because of mis-balance quotes we presume.
- I used `set -x` and the results have found an answer that work on this bash (see posted answer).

I'll just post my version as an answer; perhaps someone will have a better method or at least an explanation that lets Bash off the hook.

The concern is that the asterisks(*) are somehow Not being seen or processed as expected when the same command is used inside a Bash script.

Comment: How is #3 failing for you?  With the information you have provided, I believe it should work.

Comment: I would expect #3 to work too. What about `-path "*${target}*.pdf"` ?

Comment: Please provide the actual implementation of `get-ref`. (Most likely is that you use `$1` instead of `"$1"`.)

Comment: Beside the `get-ref` implementation, the output of the script with `set -x` would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help, we have found a working version for this script.  It is quite short so I'll post it here and give an example.

First the script, **get-ref**:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  #
  #   file:       get-ref
  #   usage:      get-ref   <pattern>  
  #
  #     <pattern> ...... target pattern to find
  #  _____________________________________
  #
  target=$1
  searchPath="$HOME/ref/"
  #
  #  _____________________________________
  #
  #
  find $searchPath   -path "*$target*.pdf"
  #
  echo    "   -------------------------------"
  echo
  exit
```

(*Debugging code omitted*).  This script looks like pattern #3 from the question.  Which may mean that I had the answer once but it didn't work for some other reason (*I hate it when that happens*).

This method worked with my friend's Bhodi Linux distro although <*shrug*> his `set -x` didn't show the single-quoting(**'**) below.   However ...

The way `-path` is handled was revealed when we used, `set -x` which showed the find command looks like this to Bash:

- `+ find /home/william/_ref/ -path` **'**`"*Java Dev*.pdf"`**'**

It seems the script (and not, the command terminal) injects single-quotes(') around the `-path` argument.  This was the missing factor.

- *praise* the [`set -x` built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

Output example:

```
  $ get-ref "Java Dev"
  + find /home/william/_ref/ -path '*Java Dev*.pdf'
  /home/will/ref/technique/games/The Well-Grounded Java Developer.pdf
  /home/will/ref/technique/bi/JasperReports 3.5 for Java Developers.pdf
  /home/will/ref/lang/ada/Ada for the Cpp or Java Developer.pdf
```

Finale ...

I'm happy that I can (now) find the document or eBook I want when I need to.  Thank you for the comments they were definitely on-track.